# Why is StreamReader.ReadToEnd() throwing in .NET Core but not .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to call a web service on an old legacy system and I pilfered some code to do that from an old Silverlight app (which I didn't write) that is targeting .NET 4. I verified the code works. However when I put that code in my app targeting .NET Core 3.1 I get the following error when calling ReadToEnd() on the StreamReader:

System.IO.IOException: 'The response ended prematurely, with at least 185 additional bytes expected.'

I created two identical console apps, one targeting .NET 4.7, the other targeting .NET Core 3.1, and sure enough, it worked on 4.7 but not on Core 3.1. I know code page 1252 is not supported in .net Core and I played around with other values to see if that was the issue with no luck.

I've found what I would consider a hacky workaround, spinning it byte by byte and using the Peek() method (ReadLine() doesn't work either) so I know I'm actually getting data back but I'm hoping the brilliant minds out there can help me understand 1) why ReadToEnd() is throwing in .NET Core and 2) whether there's a better way to do this, keeping in mind I have no control of the web service on the legacy system.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
WebRequest requestGetPODetails = WebRequest.Create(myURL);
requestGetPODetails.Method = "POST";

var postContentsBuffer = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(someXML);
requestGetPODetails.ContentLength = postContentsBuffer.Length;
using (Stream sfdDataStream = requestGetPODetails.GetRequestStream())
    sfdDataStream.Write(postContentsBuffer, 0, postContentsBuffer.Length);

// Retrieve the results
using (WebResponse responseGetPODetails = requestGetPODetails.GetResponse())
{
    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    using (StreamReader sfdDataStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseGetPODetails.GetResponseStream(), enc))
    {
        string stringResponse = sfdDataStreamReader.ReadToEnd(); // Error occurs here in .NET Core
    }
}
```

Comment: To debug - read it as byte stream - I bet you get the same error as the error likely caused by the server lying about the size of the stream rather than any client side code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to Alexei Levenkov! You were exactly right--the service was incorrectly reporting the length of the stream. I reached out to the legacy developer and he was able to fix that and now all is well.

The weird thing is that this was working under .NET Framework but not Core so something apparently changed with Core as it now cares that the length is reported accurately.

Thanks again!